# How can I avoid text and icons disappearing or breaking after laptop hibernation?

Tags: nvidia, pop-os, hibernate, optimus

Whenever I close the lid of my laptop for more than 5 seconds the following happens:

- A lot of text and icons / images disappear completely or get distorted.
- This includes app bar, menu items in top bar.
- This does not include content inside applications.

If I launch a new application, it's icon is displayed like normal.

I imagine this is some kind of memory issue when hibernating. It is if the OS is attempting to pull up whatever was stashed in memory and it is not the expected data.

System information:

**OS**: Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS x86_64

**Host**: 81LK IdeaPad L340-15IRH Gaming

**Kernel**: 5.19.0-76051900-generic

I have tried:

- Setting up a swapfile.
- Looking in settings for hibernation settings.

[image: Desktop after problem occurs]

Comment: This looks like an issue with your graphics driver. Please ask here instead: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-graphics/linux/148

Answer (score 0):

Like comments suggested, the problem was my graphics driver.

I switched from dedicated graphics to hybrid graphics using the menu in the top right, and the problem resolved itself.